# How to create pod with default uid:gid and multiple groups access gids( 4 to 5 ) that's needed to access nfs shares.?

Tags: kubernetes, security-context

I'm trying to containerize a workflow that touches nfs shares.
For a successful run it requires user to have default uid:gid and also additional 4 or 5 groupid access.
group ids are random and ideally i would like to avoid giving range of gid's in the yaml file.
Is there an efficient way to get this done ? Would anyone be able to show any examples in yaml or point me to reference documents please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The setting is called `supplementalGroups`. Take a look at the example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
...
spec:
  containers:
  - name: ...
    image: ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: nfs 
      mountPath: /mnt 
  securityContext: 
    supplementalGroups:
    - 5555
    - 6666
    - 12345 
  volumes:
  - name: nfs 
    nfs:
      server: <nfs_server_ip_or_host>
      path: /opt/nfs
```